# Set partial array of input A to a module's input

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

`XYZ` takes in **[1:0] inputs** and **QRS** has inputs of **[2:0]**.So when declaring XYZ in QRS, How to set `QRS` `a[1]` and `a[0]` to `XYZ` `a` and `QRS` `b[1]` and `b[0]` to `XYZ` `b`. **Check the comment in my code clearly understand my problem**

```
module XYZ (
    y,
    a, b
);
    output y;
    input [1:0] a, b;
  
    //....

endmodule


module QRS (
    y,
    a, b
);
    output y;
    input [2:0] a, b;
    wire w;


    XYZ xyz(w, //How to assign a[1] and a[0] to a, and same for b)
    
endmodule
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok you can do it like this

```
XYZ xyz(w, a[1:0], b[1:0])
```